# Post a message to Twitter using classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, twitter

I have a small problem. I am busy trying to get messages from a classic asp website to twitter, but I can only find examples of how to do this using php and all other kinds of different languages except for classic asp. Is there anyone here that knows how to get it to work?
I have been looking on the net for over 2 hours and found nothing that gets close. Rewriting the php api that i found will take alot of time since it's using libraries which i won't put the time in to convert as this should be a fast solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People,

I have found the solution for classic asp Twitter message posting.
Since i have been looking for it quite a long time, I'll post the solution here so other people can make use of it. Actually it's a quite easy solution :).
Here we go:

```
function asp_twitter_update(strMsg,strUser,strPass) 
    dim oXml,strFlickrUrl 
    strFlickrUrl = "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml"
    set oXml = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0") 
    oXml.Open "POST", strFlickrUrl, false, strUser, strPass 
    oXml.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    oXml.Send "status=" & server.URLencode(strMsg) 
    asp_twitter_update = oXml.responseText 
    Set oXml = nothing 
end function
```

And usage of the function like this:

```
Dim xmlStatuses,strMsg
strMsg = "Hello twitter, send with Classic ASP"
xmlStatuses = asp_twitter_update(strMsg,"yvanruth","xxxlol")
Response.Write(xmlStatuses)
```

Comment: Note that soon Basic Digest will be removed and this code is no longer applicable. OAuth is the main authentication protocol on Twitter now.